# java.util.InputMismatchException son ScannerInt

Tags: java

Buenas posteo esto por que a pesar de que lo he solucionado para que se me vea bien no entiendo por que me da. Espero me podais ayudar, tengo el siguiente código.

```
 package com.example.ejercicio1;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Ejercicio1 {
    int edad;
    String nombre, apellidos;
    Scanner teclado;
public void inicializar() {
    teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre:");
    nombre=teclado.next();

    System.out.println("Ingrese sus apellidos");
    apellidos=teclado.next();

    System.out.println("Ingrese edad:");
    edad = teclado.nextInt();

}

public void imprimir(){
    System.out.println("El usuario se llama " + nombre + " " + apellidos);
}

public void esMayor(){
    if(edad > 18){
        System.out.println("El usuario  es mayor de edad");
    }else {
        System.out.println("No cumple la edad mínima");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ejercicio1 ejercicio1;

    ejercicio1 = new Ejercicio1();
    ejercicio1.inicializar();
    ejercicio1.imprimir();
    ejercicio1.esMayor();
}
```

}

Y me da el siguiente error 
Ingrese nombre:
David
Ingrese sus apellidos
Ventas marin
Ingrese edad:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   com.example.ejercicio1.Ejercicio1.inicializar(Ejercicio1.java:19)     at
>   com.example.ejercicio1.Ejercicio1.main(Ejercicio1.java:39)

Pero si cambio la linea 19 y 18 y la pongo encima de apellidos me va bien... alguno que sepa por qué.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te da un `MismatchException` por que al usar un `getNext()` en lugar de un `getNextLine()` no te está recogiendo en la entrada el `\n`y por tanto cuando intenta hacer el `getNextInt()` está analizando la cadena "\n35" en lugar del número 35.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia que la diferencia entre Next y Nexline era que el primero dejaba el la siguiente linea \n

Comment: De hecho el Next toma como delimitador también los espacios, así que si el nombre de la persona es compuesto solo te iba a pillar el primero de ellos.